# python plotly time series handle missing dates corretly

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, timeserieschart

I am using Python 3.6 in Spyder and try to plot a graph with the plotly offline library. Anyways I have some missing dates in my csv-file and I think they cause the problem you can see in the attached screenshot. [image]

Here is my python code:

```
from plotly.offline import plot
import plotly.graph_objs as go

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('H://python/final_mk_output_regression.csv')

data = [go.Scatter(
          x=df.MESS_DATUM,
          y=df['sum_meal'])]

plot(data)
```

I can not get a correct graph. For example the part before May is very confusing. 
I have missing dates in my csv-file from 18th April until 30th April which maybe cause this problem.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Your data is messy, or the format with which the mixes read it, for me it is the first case.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I already checked my data with a count. I have no duplicate dates in my file.

Comment: share the file to review it

Comment: show your code.

Comment: sorry, edited my post with the source code

Comment: what is MESS_DATUM?

Comment: 'MESS_DATUM' is the date in the x-axis and 'sum_meal' should be the value for the y-axis

Answer (score 4):

Simply add type="category" to the code.
Here we go:

```
#PRINT DATA
data = [go.Scatter(
                x=df.MESS_DATUM,
                y=df['sum_meal'])]
layout = dict(
                title="timeline meal orders",
                xaxis = dict(
                type="category"))
fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
plot(fig, filename="overview")
```

Answer (score 3):

Only adding **type='categry'** wouldn't help because it will give unsorted date and time. You will also need to add **categoryorder='category ascending'**.

Here is the modified code:

```
data = [go.Scatter(
            x=df.MESS_DATUM,
            y=df['sum_meal'])]

layout = dict(
            title="timeline meal orders",
            xaxis = dict(
            type="category", 
            categoryorder='category ascending'))

fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
plot(fig, filename="overview")
```